# WSL Conda Environment in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to set up a new dev environment on Windows 10. Let me set the stage with some key points:

I am using Ubuntu through Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).
I have Anaconda3 installed on WSL.
I have PyCharm installed on Windows 10.

I am attempting to use a Conda environment created in the WSL within PyCharm on Windows 10. For some reason I cannot find documentation or guidance on the process.

I have already successfully setup a virtualenv within WSL as a remote interpreter for PyCharm however it will not allow me to do the same with a Conda environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some trial and error along with contacting JetBrains support, it was determined currently not possible.

My solution to get around this was to have Anaconda installed on both Windows and WSL and then create the Conda environment within Windows. I was then able to activate this environment within WSL with the absolute path to the environment.

Not the best approach but allows for editing in WSL and usage of the interpreter in PyCharm.

Comment: What do you mean by not possible? I am currently using a conda env I created in WSL as an interpreter in Pycharm using the instructions here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html and replacing usr/bin/python with /home/<username>/...

Comment: @hudson7d Do you mind sharing example how you activate Windows environment within WSL. When I try to do it I get that my Windows path to the environment is: Not a conda environment:

Comment: @SuMau "Available only in PyCharm Professional"

Answer (score 5):

This was possible by using the absolute path for the conda interpreter from within PyCharm.

e.g.

```
C:\Users\winuser\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\wslusr\anaconda3\envs\myenv\bin
```

It is now (as of very recently) not.

Comment: I've tried this on pycharm 2020.3 professional and it still works. Worth a try.

Comment: In the `LocalState` folder, now there is a file `ext4.vhdx`. I guess the internal file system of WSL is no longer directly exposed on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been able to confirm that yet, but for me it seems that the direct integration of WSL in PyCharm as Interpreter (like describede here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html) is only possible when using the Professional Version of PyCharm and not the Community Edition.

Answer (score 2):

In your project in Pycharm.

- Choose File, Setting, Project, Python Interpreter, Add
- Choose WSL on the left. Linux = your Ubuntu
- Python interpreter path = home/<your_name>/miniconda3/envs/<your_env>/bin/python3 -- this is the environment you have created in Ubuntu with Conda.

Comment: * Available only in PyCharm Professional

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can use all the conda environments in wsl as well.

1. Install Anaconda or Miniconda in your wsl
2. Set the **CONDA_ENVS_PATH** environment variable in your wsl to where your conda environments reside.
   (By default it will be /Users/.../anaconda3/envs/)

That's it after you restart your terminal and type conda list env. You can see all your environments in windows.

Incase if you dont know how to custom path for your cond envs:
check [custom](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Can you elaborate more?